# Uhhh.. something's broke!

Tags: bug

Well, all sites are now very much unusable.

Everything was working fine until 5 or 10 minutes ago.

I've disabled the two plugins that might have caused this (Adblock and Tampermonkey).

I'm running Chrome v32.

The only way to submit this question was to right-click the title box and choose Inspect Element > Edit HTML, since it's now not possible to type into the title box at all.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing the same. Do you still see it, did a full page reload solve it and are there any interesting errors from your preferred web debug tool?

Comment: Still seeing it... trying another browser now.

Comment: No repro in Chrome, Firefox/Windows.

Comment: Also what browser is that? Specific version.

Comment: Firefox is working fine. Exact version of Chrome is `32.0.1700.102 m`

Comment: Not reproducing here either, and I have tampermonkey installed.

Comment: No repro in the same version of Chrome.

Comment: Aviation is EXTREMELY broke: 1. http://i.imgur.com/kYpFZow.png 2. http://i.imgur.com/5EnkNKb.png 3. http://i.imgur.com/2bC0007.png 4. http://i.imgur.com/ixR7D3K.png

Comment: I am officially pronouncing this as the best bug report title of 2014. We don't even need the rest of the year now, we can just move on to 2015.

Comment: Clear browser cache. Restart. Disable other extensions.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I'm looking at aviation, and it is just fine (I'm on exactly that chrome version, too)

Comment: Ok so I restarted... now even this question's affected: 1. http://i.imgur.com/lglrqwK.png 2. http://i.imgur.com/CnCJFHH.png 3. http://i.imgur.com/FWuQyDi.png

Comment: @DannyBeckett can you press ctrl+shift+j, and then reload, to see if anything horrible is appearing in the browser console? (note: don't worry about "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. " - that's fine and expected)

Comment: The issue with the huge amount of whitespace has just disappeared, but the various input/button issues are still there. Accessing Aviation, the only error is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://writers.stackexchange.com/users/login/global`

Comment: Oh wait, now when I go to Aviation, I'm redirected to Writers :S

Comment: @DannyBeckett k; re the 404: in the same panel as the console, there should be a Network tab; on that panel are a list of rows of resources - are any in red? or showing anything other than "200 OK" in the Status column?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, there are lots of `304 (Not Modified)`'s - see http://i.imgur.com/OhG7KSD.png

Comment: Possibly related (I have an ongoing issue with your CDN): [New icon for Aviation](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/178)

Comment: The huge amount of whitespace is back, and now all sites are completely unusable. The only reason I'm still typing here is because I left this tab open. Is anyone seeing this comment?

Comment: Using Incognito mode, I can see the webpage again. Note it's still b0rked (not even a login button): http://i.imgur.com/TwSDxQT.png

Comment: Actually, I *am* logged in, even in Incognito mode `:S` http://i.imgur.com/O8i7xzi.png

Comment: Aviation now redirects to Portugese! WTF is going on?!

Comment: Ok well I'm going offline for 8 hours. Hopefully this magically fixes itself by then!

Comment: @DannyBeckett sounds like local issue with your ISP/DNS server which got everything messed up on their side.

Comment: Congratulations on your purchase of Facebook! http://i.imgur.com/fokXaRl.png In all seriousness, Chrome's fubar (Firefox is fine). Will reboot in a little while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the symptoms you describe, I think your computer is possessed. You may need to call in a priest or a qualified technician to perform an exorcism.

Either that, or try rebooting it and see if that helps.

<sub>(Actually, that last part is serious. Looks like your browser's gone totally bonkers; a reboot, or even just closing the browser, may help.)</sub>

Comment: Rebooting fixed it! It seems when Chrome upgraded, something went haywire! Now I'm noticing fancy scrollbars and shiz... wheee! :p

Answer (score 2):

Can't reproduce this at all. We did just deploy, so I'm suspecting:

- CDN related, but everything seems synced up, does your ISP use a caching proxy to save on bandwidth? (many caching proxies don't properly respect certain headers)
- Local cache, have you cleared it?

It's obvious that your browser has mismatched CSS/Js, but it does not appear to be coming from us. I'm going to keep trying to reproduce, but I fear this is a local (or perhaps ISP specific) issue.

Comment: Everything is being returned as `304 (Not Modified)` from the CDN. My ISP (Virgin Media) doesn't proxy that I'm aware of. I've tried force-refreshing.